# функция определения простых чисел Python

Tags: python-3.x

Помогите, пожалуйста разобраться. Понадобилось написать функцию для определения простых чисел на Python. Вот две практически одинаковые функции. Вопрос:почему

```
 def is_prime(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return False
    for i in range(2, int(n**0.5) + 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

эта функция срабатывает. А вот эта:

```
def simple(num):
    if num < 2:
        return False
    for i in range(2,int(num**0,5)+1):
        if num % i == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

выдает ошибку

> ```
> File "N:\Python my\abs.py", line 13, in simple
>     for i in range(2,int(num**0,5)+1):
>                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^  
> TypeError: int() can't convert non-string with explicit base.
> ```

Я понимаю, что квадратный корень далеко не у всех чисел целочисленный (int) и для верности его надо округлять(round). Я заменила во второй функции (int)на (round) и все работает... Но почему в первой функции все работает с (int), а вторая выдает ошибку. Благодарю.

Comment: Вот это что такое?  `0,5`

Comment: [math.isqrt](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isqrt).

Comment: "для верности" в программировании нет. Или операция необходима, или не нужна. "Верность" возникает позже, когда вы переходите недетерминированным алгоритмам. Но это совсем другая "верность".

Comment: Да, тут не "для верности", а потому, что `range` принимает только целые аргументы и нужно привести к целому аргументу )

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка состоит в том, что вы в выражении

```
int(num**0,5)
```

применили **запятую вместо точки**, и так `int(num**0,5)` интерпретируется как вызов функции `int()` с двумя параметрами: `num**0` и `5`, т. е. как

```
int(1, 5)
```

И это ошибка, потому что когда задан второй параметр (`base`), тогда первый параметр должен быть строкой или типа `bytes` или типы `bytearray`. Из [документации](https://digitology.tech/docs/python_3/library/functions.html#int):

> ```
> class int(x, base=10)
> ```
>
> ..........
> Если x не является числом или задано base, то x должен быть строкой,
> bytes или экземпляром bytearray, представляющим целочисленный литерал
> в системе счисления base.

Что касается замены `int()` na `round()` в конце вашего вопроса, то ваш второй, неумышленный параметр `5` функции `round()` значит просто округление до точности 5 цифр после десятичной точки и не требует, чтобы первый аргумент не был числом.

Но тогда, к сожалению, `round(num**0,5)` возвратит просто число `1` а не то, что вы хотели...

Comment: Допишите ещё, почему и как при этом работает `round` с теми же аргументами )

Comment: @CrazyElf, не понимаю, как функция `round()` связана с вопросом или моим ответом. :-(

Comment: Видимо, вы не прочитали вопрос до конца )) "Я заменила во второй функции (int)на (round) и все работает..." Мне кажется, такое объяснение ещё более прояснит ситуацию. Но как хотите в общем-то )

Comment: @CrazyElf, вы прав, спасибо, допишу. :-)

Comment: Вот теперь идеально )  Хотя... 1 в любой степени будет 1, и корень из 1 тоже 1, так что тут внезапно всё работает как ожидалось автором. Вот на других числах будут сюрпризы.